# When the self-similar dimension and the Hausdorff dimension are different?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

By the en.wikipedia, for the self-similar sets in a metric space, the self-similar dimension and the Hausdorff dimension are often the same, but not always. Is there a known sufficient-necessary condition for the sets whose [self-similar dimension and Hausdorff dimension are not same]?

Comment: The [Open Set Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#The_open_set_condition) is a well-known sufficient condition. There are some generalizations of this but I don't believe that there is any necessary *and* sufficient condition.